# Get site application via Factory::getApplication() in Joomla 4

Tags: php, templates, jfactory

The [documentation for J3](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Application.CMSApplication.html) instructs using `Factory::getApplication('site')` to get the site application, however according to the [documentation for J4](https://api.joomla.org/cms-4/classes/Joomla.CMS.Application.CMSApplication.html) doesn't have those method parameters anymore.

I'm working on a plugin that requires some file from my site template and aside from a database query, how can I get that template name? Is there a `Factory::getSiteApplication()` or anything?

Comment: Do you need this functionality to work in backend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specifically call the **site** application, you can use:

```
Factory::getContainer()->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);
```

In Joomla 4, `getApplication()` will always return the global application object and doesn't take any arguments.

Comment: For some reason this isn't working properly, see [Phil Taylor's gist](https://gist.github.com/PhilETaylor/0c36d87da0f2ad231b378b47c54cfb9b#gistcomment-3890308).

Answer (score 1):

The Joomla 4 core com_content component uses
`Factory::getApplication()->isClient('site');`

See: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/administrator/components/com_content/src/Extension/ContentComponent.php line 137

Comment: That's only to check if `isClient('site')` has little to do with my question.

Answer (score 0):

Link is old and here is new Link:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.3.4/administrator/components/com_content/src/Extension/ContentComponent.php#L144